# deleting rows based on conditions in column (retaining rows between two values)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 with two columns:

```
c1  <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
c2  <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,2)
df1 <- data.frame(c1,c2)
```

I want to remove rows based on a condition on column c2. I was able to acheive this using something similar to  `df1<-df1[!(df$c2==1),]` 
But my issue is I want to remove all rows between c2 values 0 and 1 (including) and keep between 1 and 2 (excluding). The number of rows between these values are not fixed in my data.
I want to achieve:

```
df2 <- data.frame(c(0,0,0,0),c(5,6,12,13))
```

Could some one help me to achieve this?

Comment: done through: df2<-data.frame(c(0,0,0,0),c(5,6,12,13))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution using the `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(purrr)
start <- which(c2 == 1) + 1
stop <- which(c2 == 2) - 1
idx <- unlist(map2(start, stop, seq))
df2 <- df1[idx, ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to read your output, sorry. Using your provided definitions for `df1` and `c2`, the above replicates `df2` assuming that the `1`s and `2`s are non-overlapping and have at least one `0` between them.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I need to exclude those values with 1 & 2 on c2 then it will be perfect

Comment: Just wonderful! Thanks a million...was thinking almost impossible with few lines of codes.

Comment: Can I ask a doubt please. When I used for my actual data, i got this error: Error: `.x` (19) and `.y` (18) are different lengths. Any advise please?

Comment: There is an unequal count of each number; 19 `1`s and 18 `2`s. The `start` and `stop` vectors contain the positions of each 1 and 2 pairing so make sure they are equal in length. You can fix this by adding lines to edit these vectors to ensure this.